# What exactly does complete in mice do?

Tags: r, statistics, imputation, r-mice

I am researching how to use multiple imputation results. The following is my understanding, and please let me know if there're mistakes.

Suppose you have a data set with missing values, and you want to conduct a regression analysis. You may perform multiple imputation for m = 5 times, and for each imputed data set (5 imputed data sets now) you run a regression analysis, then "pool" the coefficient estimates from these m = 5 models via Rubin's rules (or use R package "pool").

My question is that, in mice you have a function `complete()`, and the manual says you can extract completed data set by using `complete(object)`.

But if I use mice for m = 5 times, does it still make sense to use `complete()`? Which imputation results will `complete()` get for me?

Also, does it make sense if I only use mice with m = 1? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You probably overlooked that `mice::complete()` in arguments uses `action=1` as default, which *"returns the first imputed data set"* (see `?mice::complete`) and actually is **worthless**.

You should definitely use `action="long"` to take account for the "multiplicity" of the multiple imputation!

**No**, it makes no sense at all to use `m=1` (apart from debugging), because every imputation is based on a random process and you have to pool the results (using any method whatsoever) to account for the variation. Often `m>20` is recommended[<sup>1</sup>](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/specific/articulo/graham_olchowski_07.pdf).

Basically, **multiple imputation** works as follows:

1. Create *m* imputation processes with a random component, to obtain
2. *m* slightly different imputed data sets.
3. Analyze each imputed data set to get slightly different parameter
   estimates.
4. Combine results, calculating the variation in parameter estimates.

(Also see [multiple-imputation-in-a-nutshell](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/multiple-imputation-in-a-nutshell/) for a brief overview.)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mice`, you get an object that is not the imputed data set. You cannot perform operations on it directly without using the special functions in `mice`. If you want to extract that actual imputed datasets, you use `complete`, the output of which is a data.frame with one row per individual per imputation (if using the `"long"` format). If you are doing any analysis with your imputed data that cannot be performed within `mice`, you need to create this dataset first.