# MICE imputation

Tags: r, database, statistics, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataset like this

```
structure(list(age = c(20, 21, 30, NA, NA, NA, 50, 61, 60, 63, 
NA, NA, NA), sex = c(NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0, 1), diabetes = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA
), hypertension = c(1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    hypercholesterolemia = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
    0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Could you please tell me how I can perform MICE imputation? I want to imput all the missing values.
I tried reading tutorials on the Internet but I get errors or I don't impute everything.
Just the code with example is enough, I will adjust the settings later

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if I got it... You mean you want the user to input one value to each NA and then replace them - one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, I brought here an example. The following default settings are used in the mice function to start imputation, so I just here
brought **important parameters** which are **'m'** i.e how many imputed dataset must be generated,
**'maxit'** or how many iterations should be usesd for each imputed dataset,
and imputation method or '**method'** argument which I used here predictive mean matching 'pmm'.
But for complete explanation of these options within the mice function, see **?mice**. Then you may decide
how to adjust these options effectively.
importing your data

```
df<- structure(list(age = c(20, 21, 30, NA, NA, NA, 50, 61, 60, 63, 
                       NA, NA, NA), sex = c(NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                            0, 1), diabetes = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA
                                            ), hypertension = c(1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
               hypercholesterolemia = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
                                        0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                           -13L))
```

Start imputation using mice() function as example:

```
imp <- mice(df
             ,m = 10
             ,maxit = 10
             ,method = 'pmm'
             ,printFlag = FALSE # do not show imputation process
              ) 

#A summary of the imputation results can be obtained by calling the imp object.
imp
```

The imputed datasets can be extracted by using the complete function.

```
miceOutput <- complete(imp, action='long') # generate all completed data sets in long format
```

The imputed datasets can further be used in mice to conduct pooled analyses or to store them for next use.
Hope it could helps

Comment: @Lucas, Yes m=10 means that you will have 10 completed datasets which are identified by '.imp' column. The action= option is an option to ask how many or from which imputed dataset should be extracted. If you change action =1, then only the first imputed dataset will be extracted. action=3, the third one and so on.

Comment: Great answer +1. It should be even more emphasized that using `action='long'` and pooling the analyses is the only correct way. Often using `m` >= 20 is recommended. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059183/6574038

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(miceRanger)
mr <- miceRanger(dataframe,valueSelector = "meanMatch",verbose=FALSE, returnModels = T) # fits the models
df_final <- ampute(dataframe,mr) # ampute the data
```

You can use `valueSelector = "value"` too.

More details in: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miceRanger/vignettes/miceAlgorithm.html and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miceRanger/miceRanger.pdf