# MICE in R with specific condition for few variables

Tags: r

I am trying to analyse some medical laboratory values of patients.
These values consists of:

**leucocyte_value, lymphocyte_value, neutrophil_value, hemoglobin_value, platelets_value,
albumin_value, ldh_value, crp_value **

Each of these parameters have around 10-30 % missingness.
Now, I ran the imputation for each of these values one by one.

At the end I realized that for some patients "neutrophil_value" and "lymphocyte_value" were highr than "leucocyte_value", which doesn't make sense because netrophil and lyphocyte both belong to leucocyte. So in 100 leucocytes, there are 40-60 netrophils and 20-40 lymphocytes, rest are other cells.

So, in the imputation, I want to make sure that this condition is maintained. I would try to use regression between netrophil, lymphocytes and leucocytes values to control it, but no idea how.

My MICE command for each variable is:

```
library(mice)
library(cowplot)

#select the col with lab values of interest
cm743_imp <- cm743 %>% 
  select( wbc_value, lym_value, ntr_value, hb_value, plt_value, alb_value,ldh_value, crp_value) 
  
#check the missingness pattern
cm743_imp %>% 
  md.pattern(plot = TRUE, rotate.names = TRUE)

#run the imputation for each variable 
mice_imputed <- data.frame(
  original = cm743$ntr_value,
  imputed_pmm = complete(mice(cm743_imp, method = "pmm", m = 5))$ntr_value,
  imputed_cart = complete(mice(cm743_imp, method = "cart", m= 5))$ntr_value,
  imputed_lasso = complete(mice(cm743_imp, method = "lasso.norm", m=5))$ntr_value
)

#compare distribution of imputed vs. original values
summary(mice_imputed$imputed_cart)
summary(cm743_imp$crea_value)


cm743_imp_new <- data.frame(
  id = cm743$id,
  ntr_value = cm743$crea_value,
  ntr_imp = mice_imputed$imputed_pmm) #after visulization select one of imputation method
```

Comment: See, for example, [this](https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Passive_Post_processing/Passive_imputation_post_processing.html).

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Note that you are using `complete` **wrong!** The link from @Limey doesn't seem to do it right either. Once wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059183/6574038) about this.

Comment: Thanks for that crucial advice. But for part of the passive imputation, as suggested by -@Limey, why do you think it's not doing right either ?