# mice imputation fails when using 'where'

Tags: r, r-mice

I'm using R package `mice` for multiple imputation. I only need to impute a subset of my variables, but I thought it could be good to use the full data set for the imputation of these variables. Hence I'd like to use the  `where` flag to specify which values (and variables) to impute. However, if I set `where`, then many, or sometimes all, of the values indicated by the `where` input matrix remain NA, whereas if I don't set `where`, then all missing values are imputed. I don't know why that would be.

Using R 4.2.3, `mice` 3.16.0. Generate random data with missing values

```
library(mice)
set.seed(2024)
df <- matrix(data = sample(100,100,replace=TRUE), ncol = 5)
df[df>80] = NA
> df
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   66    1   80   43   78
 [2,]   37   75   NA   NA   16
 [3,]   45   35   67   58   36
 [4,]   60   NA   25   49   46
 [5,]   17   28   34    5   NA
 [6,]   32   48   NA   80   72
 [7,]   NA   NA   57    6   73
 [8,]   29   NA   49    3   20
 [9,]   11   NA   54   25   18
[10,]   16   NA   NA   33   34
[11,]   29   43   49   75   19
[12,]   62   58    3   NA   12
[13,]   14   20   25   30   NA
[14,]   34   55   65   NA   66
[15,]   26   NA    6   73   16
[16,]   44   60   20   61   45
[17,]   50    4    9    3   62
[18,]   26    7   79   29   70
[19,]   32   52   77   20   68
[20,]   NA   57   80   61   31
```

`where` matrix specifies that I'm only interested in imputing the second variable

```
where.mat = matrix(FALSE,nrow = dim(df)[1],ncol = dim(df)[2])
where.mat[,2] = is.na(df[,2])
> where.mat
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
 [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[11,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[12,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[14,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[15,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[16,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[17,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[19,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[20,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Imputation using the `where` matrix

```
test1 = mice(data = df, 
             m = 1, 
             ignore = NULL,
             maxit = 1, 
             where = where.mat,
             method = "pmm")
imp_dat <- complete(test1, action = 1, include = F)
```

Not all values are imputed

```
> sum(is.na(imp_dat[,2]))
[1] 2
> imp_dat[,2]
 [1]  1 75 35 43 28 48 NA 43 60 NA 43 58 20 55 43 60  4  7 52 57
>
```

Run again, now without the `where` matrix

```
test2 = mice(data = df, 
             m = 1, 
             ignore = NULL,
             maxit = 1, 
             #where = where.mat,
             method = "pmm")
imp_dat2 <- complete(test2, action = 1, include = F)
```

Now everything is imputed

```
> sum(is.na(imp_dat2[,2]))
[1] 0
> imp_dat2[,2]
 [1]  1 75 35  7 28 48  7 43 43 43 43 58 20 55 20 60  4  7 52 57
>
```

Why doesn't it work with the `where` matrix? I've confirmed that the `predictorMatrix` is correct, and it isn't a collinearity issue, since it works in the second example.

```
> test1$predictorMatrix
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
V1  0  1  1  1  1
V2  1  0  1  1  1
V3  1  1  0  1  1
V4  1  1  1  0  1
V5  1  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Noticed you're using `action=1L` which just uses the first imputed dataset (unfortunately the author set this as default). You definitely should use `action='long'`, see my [corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66059183/6574038)  as to why.